# blender crashes when i run a script

Tags: scripting

I want to use blender's import-export PDB addon to generate nice images of a bunch of proteins. There are way too many PDB files to do by hand so this requires a script. Unfortunately when I run my script, blender immediately locks up and crashes, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

How do you think this issue can be solved?

Here is the script:

```
# render-pdb.py
# bion howard - 6 june 2018

# to run:
# open blender console with shift-f4
# filePath = "C:\\Users\\bion\\Desktop\\hack\\scrapers\\render-pdb.py"
# exec(compile(open(filePath).read(), filePath, 'exec'))

# imports
import bpy, os

proteinsPath = "C:\\Users\\bion\\Desktop\\hack\\scrapers\\protein"

def clear():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

    for item in bpy.data.meshes:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(item)

# loop thru folders
for dir in os.walk(proteinsPath):
    proteinPath = dir[0]

    # loop thru pdbs
    for file in os.listdir(proteinPath):
        if file.endswith('.pdb'):

            # set background transparent
            C.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = "RGBA"
            C.scene.render.alpha_mode = "TRANSPARENT"

            # get the path to the pdb file
            pdbId = file[:-3]
            pdbPath = os.path.join(proteinPath, file)

            # import the pdb file to blender
            pdb = bpy.ops.import_mesh.pdb(filepath=pdbPath,filter_glob="*.pdb",use_center=True, use_camera=False,  use_lamp=True, ball='0', mesh_azimuth=32, mesh_zenith=32, scale_ballradius=1, scale_distances=1, atomradius='0', use_sticks=True, use_sticks_type='0', sticks_subdiv_view=2, sticks_subdiv_render=2, sticks_sectors=20, sticks_radius=0.2, sticks_unit_length=0.05, use_sticks_color=True, use_sticks_smooth=True, use_sticks_bonds=True, sticks_dist=1.1, use_sticks_one_object=True, use_sticks_one_object_nr=200, datafile="")

            # make media folder
            mediaPath = os.path.join(proteinPath, "media")
            if not os.path.exists(mediaPath):
                os.makedirs(mediaPath)

            # take a screenshot 
            screenshotFileName = pdbId + ".png"
            screenshotPath = os.path.join(mediaPath, screenshotFileName)
            bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(filepath=screenshotPath, full=False)

            # clear everything
            clear()
```

thanks in advance,
Bion @ Bit Pharma

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? You can easily comment out bits of code and see what does/does not crash. Also make sure your script works as you post it here. Now `C` is undefined.